# How to fix this error "custom query parameter not defined in target url"?

Tags: wordpress, google-sitelink-searchbox

everyone!
I have a wordpress site and I've tested it by using Rich Results Test.
But an error occurred in Sitelinks searchbox item.
Detailed error is like this.
"custom query parameter not defined in target url"
I've attached screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5UFs.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OarbO.png)

I thought this might be caused by a plugin.
So I deactived all plugins one by one and tried test again, but I couldn't find the reason.
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: It's looking for a "Search Term String".  Is there a place where you can set one in the settings/configuration of this plugin?

Comment: Thank you for your attention.
There are so many installed plugins in my wordpress site(over 70), so I'm not sure which one is the matter.

Comment: Maybe instead of Rich Results Test, use this:  https://classyschema.org/Visualisation